# how to convert string variable to array using swift

Tags: swift, swift3

I have this variable

```
var = "[\"test\", \"test\", \"test\", \"test\", \"test\", \"test\", \"test\", \"test\"]"
```

how I can convert it to be an array

```
[\"test\", \"test\", \"test\", \"test\", \"test\", \"test\", \"test\", \"test\"]
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your string contains the [JSON](http://www.json.org) representation of an array with
string elements. You can convert it to a Swift `[String]` array
using the [`JSONSerialization`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/jsonserialization) class:

```
let jsonString = "[\"foo\", \"bar\", \"baz\"]"
print("JSON:", jsonString)

let jsonData = jsonString.data(using: .utf8)! // Conversion to UTF-8 cannot fail.

if let array = (try? JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: jsonData, options: [])) as? [String] {
    // `array` has type `[String]`.

    // Let's dump the array for demonstration purposes:
    print("\nArray:")
    for (idx, elem) in array.enumerated() {
        print(idx, elem)
    }
} else {
    print("malformed input")
}
```

Output:

```
JSON: ["foo", "bar", "baz"]

Array:
0 foo
1 bar
2 baz
```

Answer (score -2):

Here, try this:

```
var input = "[\"test\", \"test\", \"test\", \"test\", \"test\", \"test\", \"test\", \"test\"]"
let components = input.trimmingCharacters(in: ["\"", "[", "\"", "]"]).components(separatedBy: "\", \"")
```